# how to add a Facebook share plugin to an array with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]I have made a JavaScript and HTML button that when clicked displays an image and a string(mentioned as source in code),
I want to add a Facebook share button to each array for the user to share the image on facebook. (I would want share button to display on to the right of the GIF.)
here is what I tried:

```js
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.10";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<!--END-->
<script>
<!--Facts-->
var currImage = 0;
window.onload = () => {
    const factsArr = [
 { image:'https://media.giphy.com/media/3o7aD5tv1ogNBtDhDi/giphy.gif', source:"<a href='http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2010/03/100315-half-male-half-female-chickens/' style='text-decoration:none;color:#FFFFFF;' target='_blank'>know more</a>",fb-share-button:"Share"},
  { image:'https://media.giphy.com/media/1nkUav308CBws/giphy.gif',      source:"<a href='http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/most-expensive-pizza' style='text-decoration:none;color:#FFFFFF;'target='_blank'>know more</a>",fb-share-button:"share"},
    ];
     const swtch = () => {
    document.getElementsByClassName('image')[0].setAttribute('src', factsArr[currImage].image);
    document.getElementsByClassName('source')[0].innerHTML=factsArr[currImage].source;
 document.getElementsByClassName('fb-share-button')[0].innerHTML=factsArr[currImage].fb-share-button;
    currImage++;
    if (currImage == factsArr.length)
        currImage = 0;
    console.log(currImage);
};
document.getElementsByClassName('generate-btn')[0].addEventListener('click', swtch);
document.getElementsByClassName('source')[0].addEventListener('click', swtch);
document.getElementsByClassName('fb-share-button')[0].addEventListener('click', swtch);
}
```

```html
<button class="generate-btn">Amazing Fact Button</button>
<div class="source"></div>
<img class="image" />
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://media.giphy.com/media/3o7aD5tv1ogNBtDhDi/giphy.gif" data-layout="button_count" data-size="small" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fmedia.giphy.com%2Fmedia%2F3o7aD5tv1ogNBtDhDi%2Fgiphy.gif&amp;src=sdkpreparse">Share</a></div>
```

Comment: Can you explain what problems you are having with what you have tried? Anything specific? Also have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: I am struggling to make a share button appear when the button is clicked along with the source and image. I dont know how to add a document.getElement for facebook,and yes the browser console didnt do much

Comment: Have you tried using `console.log()` to debug and ensure `swtch()` is being called and checked `currImage` - `factsArr.length` contain what you expect them to?

Comment: that is not the problem,It is that I cant add a new Facebook  Element to the FactsArr